# Fill background of button with color according to checkboxs that are checked?

Tags: jquery, html

I have checkboxes. When I check one it fills the button with color according to all numbers of checkboxs. That was simple. The issue is, when I get 100% of filled button the if statement makes button green. But I cant figure it out. Can someone tell me, please, why its so.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
  countEl = 100 / $('ul li input').length;
  countCheckEl =  $('ul li input:checked').length * countEl;

  $('.count').text(countCheckEl)
     $('.button-fill').css({
     'width': '' + countCheckEl + '%'
  })
     if($('.button-fill').outerWidth(true) == 100 ){
       $('.button-fill').css('background', '#43AA8B')          
     }       
  console.log($('.button-fill').width())

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  background: #DB504A;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #FF6F59 
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  padding: 20px;
}
.button {
  border: 2px solid #FF6F59;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #254441
}
.button-fill {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FF6F59;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: linear 300ms
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul> 
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /></li> 
  </ul>
   
  <div class="button" data-fill="100">
    <div class="button-fill">
    </div>
    Button
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you need to give the condition using your `countCheckEl` variable.
https://jsfiddle.net/6vmtghbh/ here is the result

change condition to  `if(countCheckEl == 100 ){`